# C 2D linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

So i have

```
struct node {
   int number;
   struct node *next;

 struct deck{
    int number;
    struct deck *next;
 };
};
```

I want to create a 2D linked list. How can i initialize something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: So, you want to make a link list of linked lists? like list<list<stuff>>? What's with the deck struct? Please elaborate on your problem.

Comment: Yes, a linked list with linked list. deck is just the name of the node. Its meant for a deck of cards.

Comment: Do you want to know how to add or delete nodes? If not, why are you using a linked list instead of a 2d array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe ?

```
struct deck{
    int number;
    struct deck *next;
}
struct node {
   int number;
   struct node *next;
   struct deck *decks;
};

struct node *current_node, *new_node;
struct deck *current_deck, *new_deck;

current_node = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof(struct node));

for (i=0; i<number_of_nodes-1;i++) {
    current_deck = (struct deck* ) malloc (sizeof(struct deck));
    current_node->decks = current_deck;
    for (j=0; j<number_of_decks_in_node_i-1; j++) {
        new_deck = (struct deck* ) malloc (sizeof(struct deck));
        current_deck->next = new_deck;
        current_deck = new_deck;
    }
    new_node = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof(struct node));
    current_node->next = new_node;
    current_node = new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to take *deck* outside *node*.  What you have is valid C++ but not C.

You could write something like this:

```
struct node {
   int number;
   struct node *next;
};


struct deck{
   struct node* nodes;
   struct deck* next;
};
```

Comment: I think you are missing a semicolon after struct node {...}

Comment: The original code is "almost valid" C. Just need to name the "internal sub-struct" ... http://codepad.org/nCh96ldh

Answer (score 1):

using cartesian system, you can. (BTW, it's not yet working for me. Trying)

```
struct node(){
    char data[10];
    node *x_link;
    node *y_link;
}
```